# Reporting summary statistics for stochastic optimization algorithms

Tags: optimization, convergence

In employing stochastic optimization for applied problems, one typically runs algorithms like simulated annealing and genetic algorithms multiple times to get a sense of overall variability. Based on obtained results, the "best" candidate solution is usually saved.

However "best" is not a very clear term, especially to researchers unfamiliar with stochastic optimization (*i.e.*, the practitioners, such as biologists). Often, the highest mode found is taken as a "best" local optimum.

Are there any reasons to report other summary statistics instead, such as the arithmetic mean or weighted mean (weighted based on the number of times a particular solution was found)?

My thinking is that since there is always uncertainty in obtained optima, it is better to consider all of them, rather than only one.

To given an example, suppose after running a stochastic optimization algorithm 20 times, we obtain the following 5 local optima:

```
optima    120 101 105 113 117
frequency   4   7   2   3   4
```

of which, the value 101 was found most often. The arithmetic mean is 111.2 while the weighted mean is 110.2

Can someone potentially point me to some authoritative literature on the topic?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I feel you are confusing the peak of a probability density, the mode, with the peak of an objective function.If you are after the global maximum of a population, then the maximum of the sample distribution is a good estimate of the population maximum.  The mean of the maximum will be much more biased.

Comment: I think I see how conflation of the peak of a pdf and that of the objective function was noted from my statement regarding the convergence in probability of a sequence of random variables. I'm just wondering when/if the mode is the "best" summary statistic to report, but I guess the best answer I can get is something like: "it depends on your specific problem of interest"...